# Keycloak's Default Page at '/auth' - How to Remove or Hide?

Tags: keycloak

What would be the best way of removing or hiding Keycloak's default page at path (without Themes): https://keycloak.eaxmple.com/auth/?

For the moment, we can't touch themes, and wondering if a way to remove/hide the page visible at '/auth' via other means?

Thank you.

[image: Default Keycloak Page at '/auth']

Comment: If you find the solution, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

We changed the themes.

1 theme for master where reference to the page was removed. We used the out of box’s theme for the master.

Other themes for the other realms.